# How to set offset between feedback and pointer when using `Draggable` in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I'm trying to make fill-in-the-blank UI by using `DragTarget` and `Draggable`.
I want to set offset between `feedback` and pointer during dragging to prevent the `feedback` from beeing hidden by a finger,
and I need to do hit-testing between the `feedback` and the `dragtarget`
How can I implement this?
 [This is what I want to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMahG.png)

## Solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _text = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: _buildDragTarget(),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: _buildDraggable(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDragTarget() {
    return DragTarget<String>(onAccept: (data) {
      setState(() {
        _text = data;
      });
    }, builder: (BuildContext context, List candidateData, List rejectedData) {
      return Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            _text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildDraggable() {
    var draggable = Chip(
      label: Text(
        'draggable',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    );

    var feedback = Transform.scale(
      scale: 2.0,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 0.5,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
          child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 0.5,
                child: draggable,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Draggable<String>(
      dragAnchor: DragAnchor.child,
      child: draggable,
      feedback: feedback,
      feedbackOffset: Offset(0, -50),
      data: 'draggable',
    );
  }
}
```

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCLfj.gif)

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution may be to add this function:

```
Offset myPointerDragAnchorStrategy(
    Draggable<Object> draggable, BuildContext context, Offset position) {
  return Offset(10, 0);
}
```

and then set the `dragAnchorStrategy` property in the `Draggable` object:

```
return Draggable<String>(
    ...
    dragAnchorStrategy: myPointerDragAnchorStrategy,
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would suggest using the `Transform` widget to scale up the selected draggable item by a bit and use it as feedback. It will also give the user a feel that the item has been picked up.

Just wrap your draggable widget with `Transform` and use `scale` property with value `~1.25`. (an example value) This will increase the size of the widget by 25%.

However, if you specifically need to add an offset for the picked Item, then just use a `padded` version of the draggable item as feedback.

For example,

If you need to add move the draggable a bit above the current touch position, then just add required padding below the draggable item.

Basically, by adding some padding in the opposite side, it gives you an effect of adding offset in the widget.

I would still suggest going for the `Transform` widget approach. It feels more genuine and is common in all similar UIs.

If you have any questions about this approach, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! I resolved it by using `Transform` and `Padding`, but I had to make more complicated widget than I thought...